# $scope object used in method without being passed

Tags: angularjs

In the following code from [this example](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_controllers.asp):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="personCtrl">

First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
<br>
Full Name: {{fullName()}}

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('personCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
    $scope.fullName = function() {
        return $scope.firstName + " " + $scope.lastName;
    };
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

How can `$scope.fullName` be set to a function that uses `$scope`, yet does not pass it explicitly?

---

I.e. why:

```
$scope.fullName = function() {
```

instead of

```
$scope.fullName = function($scope) {
```

Comment: `$scope` is already being injected in your `controller` function.

Comment: This is very basics of javascript. Read about scopes and function parameters.

Comment: ^ This. It has to be be `function($scope) {}` only if the function is called with an argument (and here it is not: `{{fullName()}}`). And `$scope` shouldn't be passed to this function because `$scope` is already available in parent function scope. As said, these are JS basics, they aren't specific to Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**
Because the *fullName()* function has closure over it's parent's scope which is the controller function.

**Long answer:**
JavaScript has function-level scope which means every function creates it's own scope. Scope is basically the variables and functions that a function has access to. When you have child function inside a parent function the child function has it's own scope but also has access to it's parent function's scope. This is known as a *closure* - the child function has a *closure* over the parent's scope. A function doesn't just have access to it's parent's scope, but it's grandparent's scope and goes all the way up the *scope chain*. A child function has *closure* over it's parent's scope, but not the other way around.

It's important to note that the $scope variable injected into angular controllers is not the same thing as scope in JavaScript. I know this confuses a lot of people that are learning JavaScript via Angular. Since the $scope variable exists in the controller function's scope any child function has access to it. The fact that the variable name is $scope changes nothing about what is actually going on.

I really glossed over this and I recommend reading up on scope and closures in JavaScript.